# Storing and retrieving Symmetric keys in Azure keyvault

Tags: azure-keyvault

Any idea if store and retrieval (export the symmetric key out of keyvault) of symmetric keys is supported in Azure Kev vault or possible? I referenced Azure Keyvault documents [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/about-keys-secrets-and-certificates#BKMK_KeyTypes) and it mentions the Symmetric keys are not supported and may be supported in future (not sure though if the documentation I read is current).

If it’s not supported, is there a way to simulate this using other interfaces like Secrets? Could you share a sample code to do this using Azure Keyvault REST API?

Comment: you are on the right track :-) Just store your keys as secrets in key vault. Which language are you using ? There are some SDK to access azure key vault. Are you calling key vault from another azure application ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right about storing the symmetric keys as secrets.

**REST API**

Here is a detailed article around the code involved to do this using REST API
http://thuansoldier.net/7329/

**.NET SDK**

Here is the nuget package 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault/

You can use the KeyVaultClient class and GetSecretAsync method.

Here is an example on Microsoft Docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-use-from-web-application

Similar SDKs are available for Node.js, Java and Python

Comment: were you able to use any of examples or looking for something different?